# How to set configuration of localhost in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, hector

My Cassandra running successfully on multiple node.And I want to run it local mode, so What changes should be need in cassandra.yml file for local mode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  Are you trying to run a multi-node cluster on your local machine, or do you just want to run a single node locally for development?

Comment: @rs_atl i am trying to run a multi-node cluster on local machine.

Comment: In that case Lyuben's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple nodes locally can be complicated if you are trying to configure cassandra on your own. You could just use [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) which is a tool that does exactly this. If you are on windows, you are going to have to configure the listen address to allow [multiple local addresses](https://superuser.com/questions/249723/how-can-i-map-multiple-hostnames-to-localhost) and configure each node to use different data, log and cache directories, also you will have to modify the various ports involved (binary protocol, thrift, jmx) to be unique to each server.